# How to deploy Service Fabric application services to different Virtual machines scale sets

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-service-fabric

I see that is possible to create different nodes per cluster.
Every node set is a Virtual Machine Scale Set.
I created a Cluster with 2 nodes set, one for FrontEnd, the other for Backend (more nodes and more powerful machines).

I have a Service Fabric Application with 3 Services.
I want 1 service to be deployed on the FrontEnd scale set and the other 2 to the Backend set.

How do I do that from Visual Studio 2015?
If I right click the application and Deploy, the deploy is successful but how do I specify which service is deployed where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at placement constraints. Using these, you can influence where services run. More info [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-cluster-description/#placement-constraints-and-node-properties).

Paragraph:

> Placement constraints and node properties